# How to find the first letter (alphabetically) in a string?

Tags: java, string, sorting, alphabetical

So I need to figure out how to find the letter that appears first in the alphabet in a string.

So far I have this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class alphStr {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a word - ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("The word you entered was: " + word);
}

}
```

I think I can compare letters within the string by using "> || <" but i'm unsure how to go about doing this. Any advice would be great!

Ended up with this solution after some reading, thanks for the help everyone.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.Arrays;

    public class alphStr {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
    String word = input.next();
    char[] chars = word.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(chars);
    String sorted = new String(chars);
    char x = sorted.charAt(0);
    System.out.println("Alphabetically, the first letter in your word is: " + x);
}
}
```

Comment: sort contents of string and get first char ?

Comment: Read the String class javadoc. You'll discover methods allowing to access characters of a String: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Stack Overflow has become kind of crappy and a lot of grumpy people seems to like to have it that way, but I have to ask (here or elsewhere?) : This is clearly homework. The submitter basically have done nothing. I could perhaps spend 5 minutes pointing in the right direction, but is there really any point when a lot of people just mash together some code just to get upvoted? I don't think it's helping anyone, or is it?

Comment: Besides, finding the lowest number in a sequence probably wouldn't require more computational complexity that O(n), don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use the `toCharArray()` method of the String class. as in

`char[] word2 = word.toCharArray()`.

After you do this, store the first letter in a separate char variable and compare each subsequent letter to it lexicographically. In this way you can find the letter which occurs first in the string (although you will have to do more work to sort between uppercase and lowercase!)

Comment: *"compare each subsequent letter to it lexicographically"* I'm pretty sure thats the part he's trying to figure out

Comment: I would suggest `word.toLowerCase().toCharArray();`

Comment: @Floegipoky Since `String` is immutable, performing `toLowerCase` will create a new String (extra object), and I really don't think case matters, as long as it's the absolute letter (uppercase or lower)

Comment: @VinceEmigh Unfortunately case does matter, because lexical comparison will yield incorrect results unless it's converted to the same case first.  Unless I'm misunderstanding OP's requirements.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I'm aware that's _part_ of what he's trying to solve, but I wasn't going to answer the entirety of what is clearly a homework question for him. I was just trying to point him in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the alphabets in the word to lowercases, and then store them in an array,
and apply a `simple sorting algorithm`, a slightly modified version of `bubble sort`, to find the first character, by comparing the [ASCII](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html) value of each character in the string.

```
char[] arr = word.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

// assume the smallest character is the character at index 0.
int first = 0;

// iterate through characters 1..n-1 to and check if any character is
// smaller than the one we have identified.
// if smaller, replace `first` with the index of the current character.
// at the end of the loop, `first` 
//will have the index of the smallest character.
for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] < arr[first]) {
        first = i;
    }
}
System.out.println(word.charAt(first));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need but I don't quite understand how it works. Could you possibly explain? If not i'll just try reading through the string class javadoc again.

Comment: @user3264285 A `char` can be represented as an `int`, and vice-versa. For example, `System.out.println((char) 74);`

Comment: @user3264285check my updated answer. You need to understand that two characters are equal if their ASCII values are equal. comparing two characters in java, compares their ASCII values.

Comment: `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` will be thrown in case of empty `String`, you should rethrow it as `IllegalArgumentException`.

Answer (score 0):

Doomsday's answer will work, but personally I would loop through the alphabet instead, a-z, and use `String.indexOf(currentCharacter)` instead.  This way you don't have to store or compare anything, just break out of the loop the first time `indexOf` returns anything other than -1.

Comment: This would be a time-excessive algorithm to use. For each letter, there are 26 possibilities. That means, for a 2 letter word `zy`, itll take 51 loop iterations just to check those 2 letters. Imagine a `String` thats 100 characters long

Comment: It also doesn't work at all if you consider that the String might contain any character value, and not just a-z (unless you're ready to loop over the 2^16 char values).

Comment: @VinceEmigh All of the solutions presented thus far, including mine, are O(n) worst case.  The computer would be more than happy to run this on a 100 character string.

Comment: @JBNizet I assumed that when OP mentioned the alphabet, she was referring to the English alphabet.  I would argue that my solution is the _only_ one that would actually conform to requirements.

Comment: @Floegipoky your solution is not O(n). It's O(m * n), where m is the size of the alphabet, and n the size of the string.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm not sure if you're trolling, confused about Big Oh, or trying to argue that the size of the English alphabet is non-constant.

Comment: Your algorithm clearly has a number of iterations that is proportional to the size of the alphabet, which is not the case of the classical algorithm. Read the message of Vince again. Your algorithm takes 51 iterations to find the max letter of xz, whereas the basic algorithm that you learn at the first day of you algorithms 101 course takes 2.

Answer (score 0):

First convert string to a Case "Lower" or upper and use toCharArray() and iterate this array till the string.length-1 and store the first char index in a temp variable and compare the char with the char array and if found the char less than this temp indexed char then store this index in char.

You can check program here : [Java program to find the first letter alphabetically in String](http://java2carrer.blogspot.com/2014/10/java-program-to-find-first-letter.html)